# The chickens clucked happily around our feet/our legs/us

Tags: word-choice

Is it possible here to change feet to legs, or isn't it possible because of chickens aren't high? I suppose, it's also possible to say: The chickens clucked happily around us (even if we are adults). Right?

> The chickens clucked happily **around our feet**.

Comment: Legs is a perfectly acceptable replacement for feet here.

Comment: *At our feet* is the more common usage but *around our feet* works too.  *Around our legs* is not the common phrase to describe things at your feet.  I would describe anything shorter than my knees as *at my feet*.  I would describe taller things as *around me*.  *The chickens at my/our feet cluck happily and the cows around me/us moo.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think of the three choices "feet" is best. "Us" would be fine. "Legs" sounds a little strange.